# What does the hominin phylogenetic tree look like?

Tags: phylogenetics

I'm no biologist, but I'm curious what the rough phylogenetic tree looks like for Hominin.  Could you create a rough sketch that includes:

- Homo rudolfensis
- Homo ergaster
- H. georgicus
- H. antecessor
- H. cepranensis
- H. rhodesiensis
- Homo neanderthalensis
- Denisova hominin
- Homo floresiensis
- H. heidelbergensis
- H. neanderthalensis
- H. sapiens
- H. erectus
- H. habilus
- any others I may have missed

Feel free to correct any incorrect assumptions I may have made here, or clarify anything that could be instructive.

Comment: Is this suitable? I am a novice so sorry if it is not: http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/human-family-tree                                              I Googled "Hominid tree" to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gonzalez-Jose *et al.* (2008)](http://www.mef.org.ar/~muspal/images/stories/investigacion/iescapa_docs/gonzales_et_al_2008.pdf) published the following cladograms, based on two analyses (parsimony versus maximum likelihood). The table shows the legend. The interesting case of *Homo floriensis*, among others are not included, likely because of their recent discoveries and limitations of the study cited.

[image][image]

**Reference**
**-** [Gonzalez-Jose *et al. Nature* (2008); **453** 775-79](http://www.mef.org.ar/~muspal/images/stories/investigacion/iescapa_docs/gonzales_et_al_2008.pdf)

Comment: Great answer, but one thing to note about the upper tree is that the Bremer support values are really really low (0.2 to 0.5) particularly within *Homo*. So basically there is no resolution at that point. They may as well have a large polytomy at that point. This is not a fault of the authors but of all these fossils being fragmentary.

Comment: @kmm - This is pretty much over the top of my head - Please advice, should I crop the image and only show the bottom tree instead? Piece of cake to do so. I simply pasted their complete figure in here without critically assessing their respective merits to the question.

Comment: No, it's fine as is. The tree is the tree and is (very likely) technically correct. It's just that the devil is in the details. I'm sure the bottom tree is equally poorly supported.